# Glslink only highlights first letter of following word

Tags: glossaries

I use the glossary package in my file to create a glossary. When I use glslink in text, it does not insert the glossary entry at that position, instead it indeed does link to it and highlights the next upcoming character as link to it. As you can see this clearly looks very dumb.
[image]

These are occurrences before the glossary file, but it also happens with occurrences after the glossary file. Haven't found anything on how to fix this. It should either mark the whole (written out) word as link or directly enter the glossary entry in text, when I link it.
Here's my (relevant) latex code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,halfparskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, toc,style=altlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\include{glossar}

First example: \glslink{glos:ESC}ESC

\end{document}
```

The glossar.tex file looks like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{glos:ESC}{name={ESC},description={Electronic Speed Controller: Controller, um einen Motor anzusteuern}}
\printglossaries
```

The glossary file is printed correctly. It shows the name and then the description. But when I reference entries in the document, it only ends up as in the picture.
(Note: In the picture is a second example, but I removed it since it shows nothing new.)

Comment: don't put `...` in your example. Create an example that is complete and can be compiled and tested. And remove irrelevant code like the bibliography or setspace.

Comment: Here you go. Is compilable and testable. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use braces around the text so that the link can grab it as argument. Loading inputenc is no longer needed in a current latex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,halfparskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, toc,style=altlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{glos:ESC}{name={ESC},description={Electronic Speed Controller: Controller, um einen Motor anzusteuern}}
\printglossaries

First example: \glslink{glos:ESC}{ESC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So that's the solution. :) Tried to give it as an argument with [] brackets, as I'm used from cites, but this threw an error, so that's what made me confused. Thanks. :)

Comment: mandatory arguments are in braces, optional arguments are in brackets.